# Access Vega's view with react-vega and React

Tags: reactjs, vega, vega-lite

I'm using [react-vega](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-vega) to display a [Vega](https://vega.github.io/vega/) chart. I'd like to access Vega's view, but don't know how to use the `onNewView` callback, which supplies the view, with React.

Here's what I thought my component should look like. Unfortunately, it never renders.

```js
export default function Chart(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({table: []}); // Populated elsewhere
  const [spec, setSpec] = useState({}); // Populated elsewhere
  const [view, setView] = useState(null);

  return <Vega data={data} spec={spec} onNewView={newView => setView(newView)} />
}
```

I assume that I shouldn't be using `setView` when rendering. However, how else can I access Vega's view?

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the case, asking the question prompts the answer. I realised that React need not be involved.

```js
export default function Chart(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({table: []}); // Populated elsewhere
  const [spec, setSpec] = useState({}); // Populated elsewhere

  const handleNewView = view => {
    // Do something with the view, such as updating the value of a signal.
    view.signal('xDomain', [props.xMin, props.xMax]).run();
  };

  return <Vega data={data} spec={spec} onNewView={handleNewView} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your original code was with `newView`.  It should have been the `view` obtained from `useState`.

```
const [view, setView] = useState()

return <Vega data={data} spec={spec} onNewView={view => setView(view)} />
```

Comment: Thank you! Whilst I'm not able to verify your answer, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Actually, I withdraw my suggestion above.  Your `onNewView` looks okay to me.